# full windows server backup with database files but not backed up through sql server

Tags: sql-server, restore, corruption

I am new to this and I have been backing up a windows sbs2011 server each night doing a full backup. The sql files are included but not backed up using sql backup program. Now one of the database files are corrupt. Can I pull the file from one of the earlier full system backups and restore it to original location to overwrite corrupt file?

Comment: How do you know the files are corrupt?

Comment: Please stop trusting full OS backups - they are not the same as SQL Server backups and I suspect you got into this situation by trying to restore or attach a database from one of these so-called "backups"...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- select * from sys.master_files

  - store the output
- shut down SQL Server
- copy ALL the database files (data and log both) from the corrupt database to a safe location

  - ideally a read-only location like a DVD-ROM or backup tape with infinite retention.
- restore the most recent pre-corruption backup of data and log files.
- Start SQL Server
- Set up [Ola Hallengren's backup solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/) for, at bare minimum, regular Full backups of everything including system databases, as well as Transaction Log backups of all Full recovery model databases.

  - Set it to write the backups to drive spindles that do NOT contain your live data or log files, so a single disk/array failure can affect the most recent backups OR the live data, but not both at once.
- If the restored database mounted at all, run DBCC CHECKDB on it.

  - If CHECKDB reports errors, go back to a slightly older backup and restore those data and log files
  - Repeat until it's clean or you run out of old backups and have to try a repair on a copy of the corrupt database files you wrote to hopefully read-only media.

    - If you have to do the repair, check for what data you lost afterwards.  Repair is a BAD idea, but if you have no backups, you have no backups.
- Conduct regular restore tests, both from your on-disk backups and your tape/offsite backups.

  - You know why!